# Horizontal line with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using `HTML/CSS` in my `Django templates` and I would like to display an `horizontal line` after my Django template form.

I'm getting a problem because my line doesn't apply CSS style :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <hr size=5px color=red noshade />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I get this :

[image]

If it's necessary, I can display my template, but the interesting part is about this line.

I tried with Tryit Editor v3.3 and it works but not in my Django template.

Thank you if you have an idea ?

Comment: I don't now if it would fix it but : `<hr size="5px" color="red" noshade />` you forgot the quotations. Plus, you should use CSS to add style to your elements not HTML attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Hopefully it will work for you.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <hr style="height:5px;background-color:red;border:none;" noshade />
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Or better way :

```
<style>
    .col-md-10 .line {
        padding-left : 8vw;
        background-color:red;
        height:2px;
        width:30%;
    }
</style>

     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <hr class = "line" />
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you applied to your line is not CSS style, but just HTML attributs.

The first thing that comes to my mind potentially disturbing Django is that the values associated to the attributes are not double-quoted. While for browsers it's acceptable, maybe Django is a bit less permissive.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <hr size="5px" color="red" noshade />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I would suggest you to move styling rules to CSS, because [separation of presentation and content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content) is actually a good habit.

Comment: I mentionned CSS because previously, I defined `class='line'` and I applied some CSS rules on this class. In my exemple, I didn't mention any CSS part ^^